# What is this regex replacing?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this line in a Ruby file loading program:

```
row_hash.map{|k,v| v.gsub!(/\A"|"\Z/, '').try(:strip!) if !v.nil? }
```

I remember adding it, though the reason escapes me. I know that `\A` and `\Z` are the start and end of a string, respectively.

I've written regexes intermittently for 15 years, but the `"|"` is what's really mystifying me?

Comment: Explanation in the top right corner https://regex101.com/r/xQ4iH4/1

Comment: The pipe isn't quoted (the double quotes are literal characters), it's just replacing a double quote at the start or end of the string with, apparently, two apostrophe characters.

Comment: @FreddieV4 I've updated your example as it accidentally contained the opening token for the ruby regex literal: https://regex101.com/r/xQ4iH4/2

Comment: @PeterHuene Ah. Probably should've used the JS flavored syntax then, as they use the same opening token. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterHuene `gsub` takes a regex and its string replacement--it's an empty string.

Comment: `if !v.nil?` should probably be `if v` since you're not going to be able to `gsub` on `false` anyway.

Comment: +1 because I find it interesting that the "balanced" look of the regex makes it more aesthetically pleasing, yet more confusing at the same time. :)

Comment: @DaveNewton hah, of course you're correct!  Had a "senior developer moment" there :)  Problems with seeing literal quote characters a little too literally.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have a method `try`, so you should add a Rails tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It strips quotes from strings.

This regex suffers from leaning toothpick syndrome. We can ease that by using `%r`, balanced delimiters, and extended formatting to ignore whitespace.

```
%r{ \A" | "\Z }x;
```

It matches a quote at the beginning of the string, or one at the end (or just before a newline).

So looking at it all together...

```
v.gsub!( %r{ \A" | "\Z }x;, '' ).try(:strip) if !v.nil?
```

The `gsub!` will apply the match until it doesn't match anymore. So it will match quotes at the beginning and end of `v` and replace them with nothing, all in place to `v`. The end result is `v` is stripped of beginning and ending quotes.

Then there's the [`blah.try(:strip)`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try). That's a Rails extension which is roughly equivalent to...

```
blah.strip if blah
```

Since `gsub!` will return null if the match fails, that means it will strip `v` only if it was in quotes. It will do it *after* the quotes have been stripped and it will only do it if there were quotes. I suspect this is not the intended behavior.

However, `strip` doesn't alter `v` in place so probably does nothing unless you're using the return value of `map` which would make this even more complicated. You probably want `try(:strip!)`.

Finally `if !v.nil?` means all that will only happen if `v` wasn't nil. Putting it at the end of an already complicated statement makes things even harder to understand.

---

This is a bit over-complicated as one line. It would be better if the nil check was done separate and the whole thing properly spaced out. I've also decided to use an if condition instead of `try` to make it more obvious the stripping only happens if the `gsub` matches, I don't think that's the desired behavior and want it to be really obvious to anyone reading it.

```
row_hash.map { |_,v|
    next if v.nil?

    if v.gsub!( %r{ \A" | "\Z }x;, '' )
        v.strip!
    end
}
```

Finally, since the behavior is really specific and finicky (and probably subtly wrong) the inner portion should be turned into a method so it can be named, documented and tested.

```
row_hash.map { |_,v| v.strip_quotes! }
```

Answer (score 1):

It replaces the quote character at the start and end of the string. It ignores other occurrences of the character. Here's a sample of how the regex works.

> http://rubular.com/r/pVMbQ9aqSl

"|" does not mean that the pipe is quoted. It basically matches **\A"** (start of the string followed by **"** ) **or** **"\Z** ( **"** followed by end of the string)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This does indeed help. Thanks for creating the rubular.

Comment: glad to be of help :)